# Is there an Illusion of Completeness of Understanding

Tags: bias

I very often find situations where someone is certain she understands something (an explanation, a thought, a set of isntructions), when, actually, there are many gaps in this understanding. I have looked among the cognitive biases, but have not found something in this line.

Is there such a Bias, or is it embeded in other biases?

Comment: Actually, this is very different from the Dunning Krugger Effect. It's about being confident that you are perfectly following a logical argument, a set of instructions, etc, when, actually, there are many gaps in your understanding. Do you know when someone explains to you how to do something, you thing you understood, but when you get to do it, you figure you haven't understood?

Comment: In my opinion, the Dunning-Kruger effect also allows a temporary overconfidence (or lack of awareness) until faced with the truth. Or would you like an answer approaching this like a working-memory fault where you forget instructions (or failed to piece them together)?

Comment: @VituTomaz There is a second answer in the question that refers to the  [illusion of explanatory depth](https://www.edge.org/response-detail/27117), which may be closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!